# How to create a github repo from a template repo and rename package

Tags: github

I've created a github repo as a Template, however I cannot see any option to change the java package name when creating a new repo from the template.

Should I be looking at git command line for more options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there does not seem to be any option to rename a package when creating a GitHub rpeository from a template, it would be easier to:

- create it from template (with the "wrong" package name)
- clone it
- open its template project in a Java IDE
- rename/refactor the package name, not only to change the folder, but also to change any Java class which is impacted by that change (hence the use of a Java IDE)
- git add/commit/push